# In PuTTY, Emacs key combination has no effect

Tags: emacs, ide, text-editor, putty

Please try to forgive this slightly off-programming-topic question. At least I'm getting this problem when porting my C++ code to Linux. The problem I'm having is very basic: some key combinations are not recognized by emacs.  One result of that is that I can't 'undo' edits in Emacs.

I'm running Putty.exe from Windows to my Ubuntu machine. The Putty character set (Window -> Translation -> received data char set) is UTF-8, and all my Swedish characters show up neatly on the console. When in Emacs however, I can't get C-_ to work. Nothing happens. The key combination on my Swedish keyboard is

```
Ctrl Shift -
```

Any pointers are helpful!

Comment: This is definitely interesting for programmers :) I've had the same thing with SecureCRT and never quite figured out how to solve it.

Comment: i didn't suggest it was uninteresting for programmers; only that it's not programming related.  The serverfault-vs-stackoverflow criteria as I understand them are "programming related or not?"

Comment: I had this problem as well and since I'll be using Emacs over PuTTY a lot, I added this to my local .emacs: `(global-set-key (kbd "C--") 'undo)` Might as well get used to `C--` for undo, as it means fewer keys and will work over PuTTY.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with just `Ctrl` and `"-"`. I do not use emacs, but I use that key for screen(1) since it is not used for anything else (and the default of Ctrl-a is not so useful). On windows (with my Norwegian keyboard) the keypress to trigger it is just Ctrl-. In konsole windows in KDE Ctrl- will decrease font size, so there I have to fall back to `Ctrl Shift -` (it used to be just Ctrl- there as well some years ago).

Answer (score 3):

When I'm editing with Swedish keyboard settings I have gotten used to undo with `C-x u` for reasons I can't remember anymore.